# How to get shift date one record only if shift lay on two dates?

Tags: sql, db2

[image]

Please check the image.
How to get one record if I insert date and time ?

e.g. date=20180815  time=231500
Fetch only 1 record what is shift date?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Consider editing it to make it clearer what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
where (shiftstartdate = :datevar and
       :datetime between shiftstarttime and shiftendtime
      ) or
      (shiftenddate = :datevar and
       :datetime between shiftendtime and shiftstarttime
      )
```

A more detailed version might make the logic clearer:

```
where (shiftstartdate = :datevar and
       shiftenddate = shiftstartdate and
       shiftstarttime < shiftendtime and
       :datetime between shiftstarttime and shiftendtime
      ) or
      (shiftenddate = :datevar and
       shiftenddate <> shiftstartdate and
       shiftstarttime > shiftendtime and
       :datetime between shiftendtime and shiftstarttime
      )
```

Comment: where (shiftstartdate = :datevar and
       shiftenddate = shiftstartdate and
       shiftstarttime < shiftendtime and
       :datetime between shiftstarttime and shiftendtime
      ) or
      (shiftenddate = :datevar + 1 day and
       shiftenddate <> shiftstartdate and
       shiftstarttime > shiftendtime and
        ( shiftstarttime < = :datetime or shiftendtime >= :datetime)
      )